# Word Macro - these steps work in separate macros, but not together

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

This switches Microsoft Word 2013 to the Home Tab:

```
Sub HomeTab()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SendKeys "%h%"
ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This opens a document:

```
Sub OpenToDoLIst()

Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\Name\Name Documents\Microsoft Word Documents\Work Menu\To Do List.doc"

End Sub
```

But if I combine the two like this:

```
Sub WorkOpenToDoList()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SendKeys "%h%"
ScreenUpdating = True

Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\Name\Name Documents\Microsoft Word Documents\Work Menu\To Do List.doc"

End Sub
```

It doesn’t switch the original document I started from when I activated the macro to the Home Tab, it only opens the document. I suspect it's not waiting for the HomeTab steps to finish in the original window, but I don't know why.

Comment: The logic looks fine and works on my PC. Are you sure the path to the file is correct? Are all users on the same OS / version on MS Office?

Comment: Shot in the dark: After `SendKeys "%h%"` add one more line `DoEvents`

Comment: Does it work if you use `SendKeys "%h%", true` instead? The true option sets "Wait".

Comment: So far these suggestions don't work. My instincts say it has to do with Word opening a new window when it opens the document, but I have no idea why this would make it skip earlier commands. 

This all came about because I had the audacity to want a Word Ribbon  to act more menu like. I wanted Ribbon tabs that contain lesser used command macros that execute and then don't make me have to manually click go back to the Home tab, which I use 99% of the time. I also can't believe I have to use SendKeys because there is no VBA to change Ribbon tabs.